# jQuery Isotope and InfiniteScroll - Appended items not being properly placed in the layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I've got Isotope on the page and it works independently. I've got InifiniteScroll on the page and it works independently. When InfiniteScroll loads new items, I append them to my container but instead of being placed properly in the layout, they all appear in a single column down the left-hand side of the container. Here's my JS:

```
$(function() {

  var container = $('#wall .page');

  container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.brick'
  });

  container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector: "nav.pagination",
    nextSelector: "nav.pagination a[rel=next]",
    itemSelector: ".brick",
    loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more items to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
    }
  }, function (newElements) {
    container.isotope('appended', $(newElements));
  });

});
```

I have a hard time believing it's a CSS or html problem since Isotope handles the initial items on the first page without a problem. I'm willing to provide more information if you can let me know what you need to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this same issue, I ended up finding the answer on my own. In my case, the problem was in the selector for my container.

```
var container = $('#wall .page');
```

The problem is that more than one item with the class `.page` existed inside of the `#wall` element. Because of this, Isotope was apparently getting confused about exactly where to put things. Always make doubly sure that your jQuery selectors are correct. For me, this fixed it:

```
var container = $('#wall > .page');
```